# Format number to currency using VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, formatting, currency

I got for you today a simple problem that already took me part of the day with no real achievement. I'm trying to format a number to display as a currency. There's many ways to do that, I think I've done most of 'em.

So here's the problem: I'm adding multiple number which can be positive and negative, I can't know. When I'm formatting at the end using `TextBox.Text = Format(variable, "C")`, I got the right format for positive numbers (which is per example `123 456,00 $`, I live in Canada) and I have `(123 456,00 $)` for negative ones. I would prefer to have the "-" symbol at the beginning.

I searched the web to find other ways to do that, per example :
    `FormatCurrency("-123 456", 2, TriState.True, TriState.False)`. That way I'm able to get rid of the parentheses but the "-" is AFTER the number `(123 456,00 $-)`.

Next one: `SpecificCulture`. so here I have `NegativeValueHere.ToString("C", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("fr-CA"))` . With that I'm back at the beginning with my parentheses with `(123 456,00 $)`. Note here that my application is running with culture set to `("fr-CA")` since that's where I live.

I tried one more but can't remember what it was.However the "$" was in front of the number like `$-123 456,00`.

Note: I'm running on VB.Net, and the number has to be formatted to be put in a readonly `TextBox`.

Comment: you want to get a value displayed as "-$123 456,00" instead of "$-123 456,00", is that correct?

Comment: Nah I want the $ symbol after the number. But the answer from nkvu fits my needs. Thanks for awsering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to work for me:

```
Sub Main()
    Dim value As Decimal = -123.45
    Dim positiveValue As Decimal = 123.45
    Dim customCurrencyInfo As CultureInfo = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("fr-CA")

    customCurrencyInfo.NumberFormat.CurrencyNegativePattern = 8

    Dim formatString As String = value.ToString("C", customCurrencyInfo)
    Dim formatStringPositive As String = positiveValue.ToString("C", customCurrencyInfo)

    Console.WriteLine(formatString) '-123,45 $
    Console.WriteLine(formatStringPositive) '123,45 $
    Console.ReadLine()

End Sub
```

You can get the different pattern values for `NumberFormat.CurrencyNegativePattern` from [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.currencynegativepattern.aspx) link.

Sorry if I'm off track

Comment: Nah that totally works. I only tried the NumberFormat.CurrencyNegativePattern on DataGridView's column and it didn't work right away with TextBox so I didn't go any further. The pattern number 8 is the one I needed. Thank you.

Comment: hey hey. what about if we want to get the other countries format? @nkvu? where could we get the complete list if let say i want to use malaysian format / any other asian currency format?

Comment: @gumuruh Run the [test program](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.currencynegativepattern.aspx#Anchor_3) provided in the link from the answer.

Answer (score 4):

You can create your own culture with a custom pattern for negative currency values.  Take a look at the MSDN library article for NumberFormatInfo.CurrencyNegativePattern.  For example:

```
Imports System.Globalization

Module Module1
    Sub Main()
        Dim simon = DirectCast(CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("fr-CA").Clone, CultureInfo)
        simon.NumberFormat.CurrencyNegativePattern = 1
        Dim test = -1234.567
        Console.WriteLine(test.ToString("C", simon))
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub
End Module
```

Output: -$1 234,57

Comment: Thanks for the tip, @Hans. I was not aware of that.