# How do I calculate the percentage from a textbox?

Tags: vb.net

[

][1]I have 2 textboxes, one has the value I want to give a discount, to give the discount I have to set the % in the second listbox by using buttons:

When I press "desconto" the panel on the right appears so I can select the percentage I want.
This is a project to finish my Highschool

My code

```
Imports System.IO

Public Class Form1

    Dim Total

    Public Sub BtnConta_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnConta.Click

        Dim quoteArray As String() = File.ReadAllLines("C:\Mesa1.txt")
        For Each Item As String In quoteArray

            Dim parts As String() = Strings.Split(Item, "€__")
            Dim number As Decimal
            If Decimal.TryParse(parts(0), number) Then

            End If

            Total = (Total + number)
        Next
        TxtBoxTotal.Text = Total

    End Sub

    Private Sub BtnSaveLstBox_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnSaveLstBox.Click

        ' Specify the file path where you want to save the ListBox items
        Dim filePath As String = "C:\Mesa1.txt"

        ' Open the file for writing
        Using writer As New System.IO.StreamWriter(filePath)
            ' Loop through each item in the ListBox
            For Each item As Object In ListBoxConsumo.Items
                ' Write the item to the file
                writer.WriteLine(item.ToString())
            Next
        End Using

        MessageBox.Show("ListBox items saved to file.")

    End Sub

    Private Sub BtnDesconto_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnDesconto.Click
        PanelDesconto.Show()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        ListBoxConsumo.Items.Add("1,45€__Pão")
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button11_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button11.Click
        Dim loc As Integer
        loc = TextBoxTeclado1.Text.Length
        TextBoxTeclado1.Text = TextBoxTeclado1.Text.Remove(loc - 1, 1)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button13_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button13.Click

        Dim percentagem As Double
        TextBoxTeclado1.Text = percentagem

        If IsNumeric(TextBoxTeclado1.Text) Then
            percentagem = CDbl(TextBoxTeclado1.Text)
        Else
            percentagem = 0 ' No discount
        End If

        If percentagem < 100 Then
            Total = Total * (100 - percentagem)
        Else
            ' Item is free
            Total = 0
        End If

        MsgBox(Total)

    End Sub

    Private Sub BtnSair_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnSair.Click
        PanelDesconto.Hide()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        TextBoxTeclado1.Text = 1
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
        TextBoxTeclado1.Text = 2
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
        TextBoxTeclado1.Text = 3
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button5_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button5.Click
        TextBoxTeclado1.Text = 4
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button6_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button6.Click
        TextBoxTeclado1.Text = 5
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button7_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button7.Click
        TextBoxTeclado1.Text = 6
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button8_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button8.Click
        TextBoxTeclado1.Text = 7
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button9_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button9.Click
        TextBoxTeclado1.Text = 8
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button10_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button10.Click
        TextBoxTeclado1.Text = 9
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button12_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button12.Click
        TextBoxTeclado1.Text = 0
    End Sub

End Class
```

I tried

```
Dim percentagem As Double
        TextBoxTeclado1.Text = percentagem
        Total = Total / percentagem * 100
        MsgBox(Total)
 Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        ' Specify the file path from where you want to load the contents
        Dim filePath As String = "C:\Mesa1.txt"

        ' Check if the file exists
        If File.Exists(filePath) Then
            ' Read all lines from the file
            Dim lines() As String = File.ReadAllLines(filePath)

            ' Clear the existing items in the ListBox
            ListBoxConsumo.Items.Clear()

            ' Add each line to the ListBox
            For Each line As String In lines
                ListBoxConsumo.Items.Add(line)
            Next
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

This is part the final part of the project, its a restaurant program where you choose the items the person wants(in this case i only have "button1" gives me 1 bread at the cost of 1,45) , everything is is saved in a textfile after i press save), when i open the forms it will load the textfile so i can see what the order is or in case they client asks for something else.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`percentagem` is never set in your code so it will be 0. This line is probaly backwards:

```
TextBoxTeclado1.Text = percentagem
```

It looks like you are trying to assign the value of `TextBoxTeclado1.Text` to the `percentagem` variable. This code is doing the opposite, it is setting the TextBox's text to 0 in this case (since `percentagem` has no value).

You should also check if the text entered in `TextBoxTeclado1` is numeric before updating `Total`. If it isn't numeric, use 0 as the discount:

```
Dim percentagem As Double

If IsNumeric(TextBoxTeclado1.Text) Then
    percentagem = CDbl(TextBoxTeclado1.Text)
Else
    percentagem = 0 ' No discount
End If

If percentagem < 100 Then
    Total = Total * (100 - percentagem)
Else
    ' Item is free
    Total = 0
End If

MsgBox(Total)
```

In this code I also check if `percentagem` is less than 100 but you can do further data validation, checking that it is also greater or equal to 0 in which case you could display an error message.

---

EDIT

Each button in the panel where you enter the discount should append (using `&=`) a value to `TextBoxTeclado1.Text`:

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    TextBoxTeclado1.Text &= 1
End Sub

Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    TextBoxTeclado1.Text &= 2
End Sub

Private Sub Button4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
    TextBoxTeclado1.Text &= 3
End Sub

...
```

Then, Button13's Click event handler should look like this:

```
Private Sub Button13_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button13.Click

    Dim percentagem As Double

    If IsNumeric(TextBoxTeclado1.Text) Then
        percentagem = CDbl(TextBoxTeclado1.Text)
    Else
        percentagem = 0 ' No discount
    End If

    If percentagem < 100 Then
        Total = Total * (100 - percentagem)
    Else
        ' Item is free
        Total = 0
    End If

    MsgBox(Total)

End Sub
```

Comment: I tried ur code, and it gave me a bigger number, instead of giving a discount, for somereason i can only put one value in the "TextBoxTeclado1" , if u have a discord or anything else to help a man out here, mine is mary_bu#6203

Comment: @AirtonAguiar Can you update your question with the code that updates `TextBoxTeclado1.Text` so we can see how that works?

Comment: I have updated with all the code ty @Étienne Laneville

Comment: @AirtonAguiar Remove the line `TextBoxTeclado1.Text = percentagem` from your code, this is handled in the `percentagem = CDbl(TextBoxTeclado1.Text)` statement. Also, in each `Button10_Click` handler, you should append the new value to the end of the contents: `TextBoxTeclado1.Text &= 9`

Comment: I have done it, and its working but everytime i add a number it adds a 9 at the end,, if i dont add this line of code `TextBoxTeclado1.Text &= 9` i can only give 1 digit discount
And is there a way to revert the discont?
thank you btw, it was a big help already - @Étienne Laneville

Comment: @AirtonAguiar update each Button click handler with the correct value. For example, the button with 5 on it should have `TextBoxTeclado1.Text &= 5` in its click event handler code. Then, I imagine you have a Clear button where you would do `TextBoxTeclado1.Text = 0` (force TextBox content to 0).

Comment: last thing i need @Étienne Laneville is, the Total ends up bigger by having the comma after, i have updated the program with the image so u can see, the total was 5,80 and i gave 80% discount and it gave me 116 as the total, should be 1,16.
How do you solve this?  [https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ei1o4.png]  the image

Comment: @AirtonAguiar see [Format number to currency using VB.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15709876/format-number-to-currency-using-vb-net) and [Strings.FormatCurrency](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.strings.formatcurrency).